# Objects Blinks from distance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

Some of the gameObjects in my scene blinks when move a little away from them.
I don't know why its happening and how to solve it.
I have searched for it but haven't find any solution.

Comment: Hi, is the Game 2D? If So then I think its Camera issue mostly the Z index value of the Camera needs to be changed to -1 or less.

Comment: No it's 3D. and I don't think it's in camera i'm facing the same problem in scene window

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

In 3d engine there is often a distance cutoff - things N *whatevers* away are not drawn to simplify the scene and speed up rendering/computations.

This is probably a setting on your camera or on your global scene - look for *view distance*, *clipping planes* or something similar in settings.

See **"Clip Planes"** in [the documentation of your camera object](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Camera.html)

For professional games instead of "not being drawn" they may be replaced by a less complex object because details are not visible by this distance (you need to do coding to get to that though). Or complex textures are replaced by lesser complex ones the farther away the object is.

Comment: I have tried by changing values of field view and clipping planes. but it's no use